# Remove items from NatCombo

Tags: java, swt, nattable

I am developing an eclipse plugin where I have a `NatCombo` (dropdown box) inside the `NatTable`. I need to dynamically change the combo box filter dropdown menu. I can set Items to my combo box using `natCombo.setItems()` method (where I can add my filtered list of filters).

However I could not find a method that removes items instead, or that empties the previous items in the combo box before I add new items. I can only add indefinitely Items to my combo box drop drown menu.

Is there a method to remove items? Can I implement one? If so how exactly could I?

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to do? I never heard that someone uses the NatCombo inside NatTable solely. There are neither add nor remove methods as it is inteded to be used inside an ICellEditor. And there it is created everytime, no need for modifications while it is open. So I don't understand your use case.

Comment: sorry, NatCombo is inside ICellEditor as you said. I am neither able to dispose the natcombo and recreate it with new dropdown values(in which case an exception is thrown) nor modify the combo box. i.e, remove old values from the dropdown before adding new values using natCombo.setItems(). Please help me, I don't have enough understanding on natTable/natCombo life cycle..

Comment: To be more specific, I am adding auto complete feature to already existing natCombo(done by my senior who has quit his work)..I am unable to trace things and proceed. As the key is pressed the result in the natCombo drop down should change dynamically. I am fetching required values dynamically(inside keyListener to natCombo) and set those values but just not able to remove old values from the natCombo before setting the new values..Any solution?

Comment: auto complete or filter? If you want to implement something like an auto complete I'm not sure if NatCombo is the right place. Does it need to be in a combo or do you just need auto complete? In that case with NatTable 1.4 the content assist from JFace will be supported in the `TextCellEditor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your use case and whether you are using one of our default editor implementations or created your own. But there are basically two answers, dependent on your use case:

1. You want to provide dynamic content to a combobox - this is done via `IComboBoxDataProvider` and explained in our FAQ https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=faq
2. You want to filter the content of an opened combobox - this is not supported in versions <= 1.3.0 but will be added with NatTable 1.4.0 which is on its way while writing this answer. The snapshot is already available if you want to give it a try.

Comment: Yes I want to provide dynamic content to a combobox via IComboBoxDataProvider. I have done it as well but the dynamic contents to natcombo are added only when you select the combo(the cellEditor) for the first time but not FOR EACH KEY PRESSED dynamically. So, I have used a key listener to natcombo inside the getValues() where I am trying to set values to combo.

Comment: Again, what you are trying to do does not work. Either you want to achieve content assist, then use the NatTable 1.4 content assist of the TextCellEditor or you want to achieve filtering, then use the NatTable 1.4 filterable NatCombo.